# How can i use join in LinqPad against SE DE?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services, odata, linqpad

i use [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom) service with LinqPad and i use this Code for Select all of User:

```
from m in Users
select m
```

now i want select all Posts of User

```
from u in Users
join p in Posts on u.Id equals p.OwnerUserId
select u
```

but it's not working. Where is my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get an inner join in a WCF Data Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878567/how-do-i-get-an-inner-join-in-a-wcf-data-service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're problem is not with LinqPad, it's with the OData protocol.  It does not support the JOIN concept currently.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878567/how-do-i-get-an-inner-join-in-a-wcf-data-service) and follow the link to another forum where this is discussed in more detail.

I hope this helps.